# Trying to decipher morsecode from CSS keyframes

Tags: css, morse-code

I'm playing an online escape room and in there there is a flickering light which we know is morsecode.
We found the following css code:

```
@keyframes mysteryLightFlicker  {
    0%, 1.38889% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    1.38889%, 2.77778% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    2.77778%, 6.94444% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    6.94444%, 9.72222% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    9.72222%, 13.8889% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    13.8889%, 15.2778% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    15.2778%, 16.6667% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    16.6667%, 18.0556% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    18.0556%, 19.4444% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    19.4444%, 22.2222% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }
    22.2222%, 23.6111% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    23.6111%, 25% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    25%, 29.1667% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    29.1667%, 31.9444% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    31.9444%, 33.3333% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    33.3333%, 34.7222% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    34.7222%, 38.8889% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    38.8889%, 40.2778% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    40.2778%, 44.4444% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    44.4444%, 45.8333% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    45.8333%, 47.2222% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    47.2222%, 50% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    50%, 54.1667% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    54.1667%, 56.9444% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    56.9444%, 58.3333% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    58.3333%, 59.7222% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    59.7222%, 63.8889% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    63.8889%, 65.2778% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    65.2778%, 66.6667% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    66.6667%, 68.0556% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    68.0556%, 69.4444% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    69.4444%, 70.8333% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    70.8333%, 72.2222% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    72.2222%, 75% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    75%, 76.3889% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    76.3889%, 79.1667% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    79.1667%, 83.3333% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    83.3333%, 84.7222% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    84.7222%, 86.1111% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    86.1111%, 88.8889% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    88.8889%, 90.2778% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    90.2778%, 91.6667% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    91.6667%, 95.8333% {
        background-color: #0006;
    }

    95.8333%, 98.6111% {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }
}
```

We have received a hint: *You're on the right path with the keyframes!
Take a closer look at the percentile difference of every keyframe.
NOTE: there is an additional level of obscurity in the morsecode itself in the form of a space with the same length as a '.'*

There are 3 differences, 1.38889%, 2.77778% and 4.16666%. We thought that 1.38 would be a dot, 2.77 would be a dash and 4.16 would be a space. But this is not the case and will lead to unexisting characters.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comment. I found the bigger percentile difference and was unsure... But they talk about a `.` in the text. Try 4.16 as a full stop... 